# Execute cron programmatically php

Tags: php, cron

I have created a cron job on linux server, which run once a year, which is working perfectly.

Now i have a situation that i also want to execute this cron file when click on button.
Please suggest that how to code on button click for execute the cron

I have also tried this

`exec("php /home/...../cronfile.php");`

Comment: in cronfile.php, it is getting data from an API and store in database. But in response it is talking too long time. So on button click i have called ajax

Comment: What error message (if any) do you get?

Comment: When i click on button, then it calls ajax but not responding

Comment: You said that the job is taking too long. Isn't there a timeout at AJAX request?

Comment: tried to add php with path: usually /usr/bin/php?

Comment: tried exec('/usr/bin/php /home/...../cronfile.php', $out);
var_dump($out); to show an console error ?

Comment: I have tried exec('/usr/bin/php /home/...../cronfile.php', $out); var_dump($out); but just it is spinnng not responding